# differentiate whodunnit recorded AdminUser or User - paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

```
  def user_for_paper_trail
    admin_user_signed_in? ? current_admin_user : current_user
  end
```

This is how my paper_trail is recording the user ID, but how can I differentiate that `whodunnit` recorded an `AdminUser` or `User`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to add a column called `whodunnit_type` to your `versions` table.

Then you can add a method called `info_for_paper_trail` to your controller that stores the model's class name:

```
def info_for_paper_trail
  { whodunnit_type: (admin_user_signed_in? ? current_admin_user.class.name : current_user.class.name) }
end
```